# Creating a function that can convert a list into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function that will convert a given list into a given dictionary (where I can specify/assign values if I want).

So for instance, if I have a list

```
['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z']
```

and I want to convert to a dictionary like this

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', ..., 26: 'z'}
```

I know how to do this using a dictionary comprehension

```
{num : chr(96 + num) for num in range(1, 26)}
```

but I can't figure out how to make this into a more generalized function that would be able to turn any list into a dictionary. What's the best approach here?

Comment: What's the rule to _**turn any list into a dictionary**_?

Comment: Where do the keys of the dictionary come from?

Comment: @aircraft using ints for dictionary keys is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass [`enumerated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) list to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor

```
>>> items = ['a','b','c']
>>> dict(enumerate(items, 1))
>>> {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Here `enumerate(items, 1)` will yield `tuple`s of element and its index. Indices will start from `1` (**note** the second argument of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)). Using this expression you can define a function inline like:

```
>>> func = lambda x: dict(enumerate(x, 1))
```

Invoke it like:

```
>>> func(items)
>>> {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Or a regular function

```
>>> def create_dict(items):
        return dict(enumerate(items, 1))
```

Comment: this is really good, thank you for your help here. I was going down the entirely wrong path but this is super helpful and informative. much appreciated!

Comment: if my list was something like l = ['abcd'] and I wanted to add in commas to make the output look like a, b, c, d where would I add that into your code? Would I have to add a .split() somewhere in there?

Comment: Not entirely sure about this one but you can try `list(l[0])`, where `l` is `['abcd']`

Comment: also, is there a way to call the values/keys when creating a dictionary this way?

Comment: @David all normal `dict` operations can be done on resulting dict. Can you provide an example of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are just the index of the element in the `list`, as in your example:

```
{i+1: x for i, x in enumerate(mylist)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list and assign every value to a number (starting from `1`).

```
def list_to_dict(items):
    return {n + 1: items[n] for n in range(len(items))}
```

Replace `n + 1` with `n` if you want the dictionary to start from zero.