# Converting a list or string into a dictionary and returning only specific keys/values from that dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I've been working on a function that can convert a list/string into a dictionary and I'm able to run it on a bunch of different samples successfully. For instance, I took a list of the letters in the alphabet (a-z) and assigned them a number (1-26):

```
import string
mylist = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

def list_conversion(items):
    print(dict(enumerate(items, 1)))
```

so when I call `list_conversion(mylist)` I get the output that I'm looking for:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
```

However, I'm not sure how to run this function and only return specific keys/values. For instance, I want to return on the values for odd number keys. I understand how to do this in an isolated instance:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3} 
for key, value in d.items():
    if value%2 != 0:
        print(key)
```

But I can't figure out how to build this into my function correctly. How would I build such a for loop into my function that returns only even/odd values and more broadly, how can I return only specific keys/values that I choose from this function? I thought that something like this would work:

```
def list_conversion(items):
    print(dict(enumerate(items, 1)))

list_conversion(mylist)

for key, value in mylist.items():
    if value%2 != 0:
        print(key)
```

However, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` so I get the sense I'm going down the wrong path here.

Comment: You are asking about a *key function*, which @g.d.d.c demonstrates below.      Also your function does not return anything yet.  Always return the result of a function rather than print inside it.  You can always print after the function is called.  Finally, you don't have to cast the string to a list.  The string is already iterable and will work just fine.  You are actually making a general `to_dict` function, applicable to any iterable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a function that can convert a list into a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454827/creating-a-function-that-can-convert-a-list-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

To answer the more broad question, you need to provide some mechanism by which you can determine whether or not the key is allowable for your result.  I would modify your function like so:

```
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> def list_conversion(alist, filterfunc = None):
...   # Handle the case where you just want all values
...   if filterfunc is None:
...     return dict(enumerate(alist, 1))
...   # Handle other cases where filterfunc is a callable
...   return {k: v for k, v in enumerate(alist, 1) if filterfunc(k)}
... 
>>> list_conversion(string.ascii_lowercase, lambda x: x % 2) # odds
{1: 'a', 3: 'c', 5: 'e', 7: 'g', 9: 'i', 11: 'k', 13: 'm', 15: 'o', 17: 'q', 19: 's', 21: 'u', 23: 'w', 25: 'y'}
>>> list_conversion(string.ascii_lowercase, lambda x: not x % 2) # evens
{2: 'b', 4: 'd', 6: 'f', 8: 'h', 10: 'j', 12: 'l', 14: 'n', 16: 'p', 18: 'r', 20: 't', 22: 'v', 24: 'x', 26: 'z'}
```

You can pass a more specific function in as well:

```
>>> def arbitrary(key):
...   wanted = [1,5,12,13,15]
...   return key in wanted
... 
>>> list_conversion(string.ascii_lowercase, arbitrary)
{1: 'a', 15: 'o', 12: 'l', 5: 'e', 13: 'm'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You better take the `print` out of the function.

```
def list_conversion(items):
    return {i: x for i, x in enumerate(items, 1) if i % 2 == 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Various changes to your code. `list_conversion` should return a dictionary. No need to convert `string.ascii_lowercase` to a list, as `enumerate` will iterate over the elements of the string. Finally, I use a list comprehension for efficiency rather than a loop.

```
import string

def list_conversion(items):
    return dict(enumerate(items, 1))

mylist = list_conversion(string.ascii_lowercase)
[k for k, v in mylist.items() if k%2 != 0]

# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25]
```